# sum() not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, sum

I have a query that pulls the monthly income of individuals. What I would like to get the sum of their different incomes (2 jobs, pension, etc). Since they are monthly values I also need to multiply by 12 to get their total yearly income

```
select DISTINCT f.monthly * 12 as [Income]
    FROM 
    Money
    WHERE
    ID_ = 5
    AND type = 'income';
```

this gives me

```
Income
6756
32772
```

this is how I'm trying to total the column

```
select DISTINCT SUM(f.monthly * 12) as [Income]        
        FROM 
        Money
        WHERE
        ID_ = 5
        AND type = 'income';
```

This gives me

```
Income
237168
```

When the total should be  39528. I've tried moving the brackets so it sums the column first then multiplies by 12, but I get the same result

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `distinct` inside the `sum` function, not outside...

```
select SUM(DISTINCT f.monthly * 12) as [Income]        
    FROM 
    Money
    WHERE
    ID_ = 5
    AND type = 'income';
```

Comment: thank you that also worked! I'm working this into a much larger query so this is neater than a subquery which is extra nice

Answer (score 3):

The `distinct` in the original query is just wrong - if two people have the same income, it would only take one of them. The `distinct` in the second query isn't wrong per-se, it's just pointless. `SUM` returns a single row, so applying `distinct` to it won't do anything.

To make a long story short - lose the `distinct` modifier from both queries and you should be OK.

Comment: I need the distinct for the first query because I have some duplicates. I took out the distinct for the SUM() query and it did nothing. The comment below you about the subquery is correct

Comment: @tdm - Mureinik has a really good point here: while `DISTINCT` appears to solve your problem by eliminating some redundant records, it seems possible from the admittedly little we know about your data design that there could be two records with the same income that are _not_ redundant. `DISTINCT` is sometimes genuinely useful, but my experience is that most usages of it are wrong—when I find it in existing code, I usually discover that it was used to compensate for a logic error elsewhere in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You need subquery :

```
select sum(income)
from (select distinct f.monthly * 12 income
      from Money
      where ID_ = 5 and type = 'income'
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly it